# Have error while creating table in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an error in creating table with following command:

```
Create table Sells
(Store_name varchar2(20) no null,
ISBN char(15) not null,
Unit_price number(3,2) not null,
Shipping_fee number(3,2) not null,
primary key(Store_name, ISBN),
foreign key (Store_name) references Bookstore(Name) on delete cascade,
check(Unit_price>0),
foreign key (ISBN) references Books(ISBN) on delete cascade;
```

It says:

**ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis**

Not able to figure out where is the mistake.
Anyone provide some help on why this is wrong?

Comment: Create table Sells ( <- this parenthesis is never closed... possibly before the semi-colon at the end?

Comment: You might want to correct that `no null` in the second line, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
create table sells
(
  store_name varchar2(20) not null, 
  isbn char(15) not null, 
  unit_price number(3,2) not null, 
  shipping_fee number(3,2) not null, 
  primary key(store_name, isbn),
  foreign key (store_name) 
    references book_store(name)
      on delete cascade, 
  check(unit_price>0),
  foreign key (isbn) 
    references books(isbn)
    on delete cascade
);
```

Comment: what is the modification that you have done? It is still the same and giving error!

Comment: @user666748: look very near the `cascade` at the end. :)

Comment: Well, I cannot fully test the ddl because I do not have the definition of the referenced tables, but your original code said "no null" and was missing a parenthesis at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Create table Sells 
(Store_name varchar2(20) **not** null, 
ISBN char(15) not null, 
Unit_price number(3,2) not null, 
Shipping_fee number(3,2) not null, 
primary key(Store_name, ISBN), 
foreign key (Store_name) references Bookstore(Name) on delete cascade, 
check(Unit_price>0), 
foreign key (ISBN) references Books(ISBN) on delete cascade**)**;